# yAxis resize controlled axis prev option not working Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have some highstock chart series with multiple yAxis. When I used resize enabled to true, a resizer comes and it resizes the chart as well. I want only one resizer at the bottom of 3 series which resizes the previous axis also. I think my top property in yAxis is preventing the charts from going above another axis. Please help.

I tried controlled axis previous property. which dint work

```
           yAxis: [{  
                   labels: {
                   align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                height: '65%',
                lineWidth: 2,
                id:'cdStick'                           

            }
            , {           
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                lineWidth: 2,
                offset: 0,
                id:'vol'
                resize: {
                enabled: true,
                controlledAxis: {

                    prev: ['cdStick']
                }
                     }
            }]
```

Comment: I think it is impossible to resize multiple charts with one resizer, You can only resize 1 chart with its multiple y axis inside it, but can not for multiple charts

Comment: sorry, I have multiple series actually inside the same chart container. Is it possible to resize yAxis[0] and yAxis[1] at the same time where yAxis[1] has the resizer? p.S. yAxis[1] has some top of 25%. I had to use the top because I dont want the series to overlap

Comment: I think your problem is related to this document : [Resizer](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/yaxis/multiple-resizers)

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes it is related. I want to resize the ohlc series as well with the help of macd resizer. I will remove the resizer from ohlc series later as a requirement from my client

Comment: Could you reproduce your chart in an online code editor like jsfiddle, codepen?

Comment: [here is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/59h3yktw/) Only one axis related to the resizer is working, I want to resize both the axis above the resizer. Please help

Comment: Hello, @WojciechChmiel have you checked it?

Comment: Can we have a candlestick and volume in a single yAxis?

Comment: This feature is not supported by the `drag-panes` module. It is a custom project, so if you want to do it you can contact BlackLabel company: hello@blacklabel.pl. Yes, you can have a candlestick and volume in a single yAxis: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8u3g2x5w/1/